# Why are there still so many duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I often see duplicate questions. What can we do about all the duplicate questions?

Some discussion points:

- Is the "**Questions that may already have your answer**" not clear enough?
- Should it be made more difficult before you can ask a question?
- Should there be a ban for a certain time when it happens too often?

Comment: Generally because people are either too lazy to search, or because they don't know what to search for. Neither of those problems are really going to go away.

Comment: Add to that that people *understand too little about their problem* to recognise duplicates as being helpful to their situation.

Comment: Umm, the irony?

Comment: Was this just a cleverly disguised meta meta post designed to draw attention to the problem? Bravo, even if unintentional.

Comment: Hilarious to see this phrased with "still", and so many years ago. The problem is naturally destined to get worse over time, and it is far worse now than it was when this was posted.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that everyone wants an answer to *their* problem.

Sure, they could find that so-called "duplicate," adapt it to their own needs, and write the code based on that, but why go to all that trouble when you can just use the magic code-writing machine that is Stack Overflow?

> I found question X, which is similar, but it doesn't really accomplish what I'm looking for. Can you explain to me how to fix this code where I get the same error?

```
|Insert block of code 100+ lines long here|
```

(Obviously paraphrased: there are usually more typos.)

---

In all seriousness, that *is* the problem. When there are so many active users willing to do anything to gain reputation, a question that is a duplicate can be asked hundreds of times and still receive an answer.

In fact, they may be *more* likely to receive an answer than non-duplicates because people who have solved the question time and time again can easily regurgitate the same answer, changing the variables around to fit the exact situation of the asker.

That's why we **close** questions that are duplicates: it prevents them from being answered in the same way that old questions have been answered by people looking to gain some quick and easy reputation.

If a question comes along that is 99% identical to the canonical question, but happens to have been asked better or generated *better* answers than the original, it may be worthy of [a merge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/), but that is quite rare.

In short, if you come across a question that you know is a duplicate, flag it as such or, when you have enough reputation, vote to close it.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think they aren't clear enough... they could be better of course (there was a mention here recently of someone who only finds duplicates AFTER he posted his question... maybe they could map the "Questions that may already have your answer" to the "Related" query?
2. The whole point of this site is to let people log in and ask questions as they start.... I don't think it's appropriate to force someone to answer before asking (there are certain SUPER high rep users with no answers)
3. Most of the time users who get downvoted have no rep anyway, so they will just create another new account and ask bad questions with that new account.

It's unfortunate, but I don't see it going away :(

Comment: 4 - they have already seen the dups but want the answer rewritten so that, when they copy/paste into their homework, it does not precisely match the answers that the other 'students' have copy/pasted from the dups.  Hence the plaintive cries of  'it's still not clear', 'I've already seen the other answers and read the 36,200,000 results returned by Google but I still don't get it' etc etc.

Comment: @MartinJames  good grab, I didn't actually think about that.... I did just flag a question for closure because the guy basically put in his question these exact words :P ("I see the tutorials online but I can't seem to reproduce, can someone give code so I understand better?")

Comment: Never underestimate the selfish medacity and chutzpah of 'students' who just want answers while not putting any effort in themselves.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm an optimist.... or I haven't been active on SO long enough to not be cynical about it :P.... yet

Comment: Here's one: 'I tried looking for similar questions that could find an answer to my question but i couldn't seem to find it':
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269628/c-how-to-read-certain-lines-from-a-file-not-all-lines-or-entire-file-but-ju